# C# Visual Studio Local Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I have a C# application that is using a local SQLite3 database.  I need to package the database with the application.  I am currently just interacting with the database from my desktop.  I am just connecting to the database from the desktop using the database path.

Where should I store this database, so the application can access this when I package, and distribute it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put your database file in a read/write folder.
The exact position depends on the usage of your database. 
If every user of the computer should be able to use the database then choose

```
C:\programdata\yourfolder
```

if every user of your program has its own database then a folder inside the user profile will be good

```
C:\users\username\documents\yourfolder
```

or

```
c:\user\username\appdata\local\yourfolder
```

where *yourfolder* will be a folder name of your choice referring to your application name
and *username* is the name of the current installing user of your application

These paths vary with the operating system where you deploy your application, so to be free from the operating system differences remember to use the [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://www.bing.com/search?q=environment.getfolderpath&qs=HS&form=QBLH&pq=envir&sc=8-5&sp=1&sk=) method and [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enum

Of course you can always choose to install your database in a particular folder you create during setup like C:\database or, if you plan to share your database in a network location, choose an existing sharename or create a new one.

At the end of the setup work you need to update the connectionstring stored in your config file with the value where you have stored the database file.

Comment: Is this the method I should use if I am not creating the database tables with code?  I have an already semi-populated database

Comment: Yes, prepare your database file for distribution and use a setup tool to choose the location where to place the file. The same setup tool should allow you to update the config file of your application

Comment: Just for clarification, what do you mean by prepare the database file, and use a setup tool?

Comment: A setup tool (InstallShield, the same setup project of Visual Studio or many others free/paid tools) allows you to prepare a single executable (or MSI) that contains your app, its data files (database, graphics or what else) and the actions to be executed on the customer machine to 'setup' your application for first use (copy files, update configuration files, create folders, set permissions etc...)

Comment: I stored the database in Program Files (x86)\Common Files but I do not have write access apparently, where do I have write/read access to for a database?

Comment: That's one of the locations to avoid in a Window7 or Vista computer. You should choose one of the examples shown above.

Comment: programdata is a read only as well, and the last two you mention, how do you access them to save in the installer, I only see special folders?  Also, using the Enviroment. how to get the path?

Comment: It depends from the tool you use to install your application. It should have these predefined folders to choose from. What kind of installation tool are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio .NET installer, if you recommend another, let me know and i'll give it a shot

Comment: thanks a lot I used the AppData folder, the installer was just a pain!